# Is revolutionist a real word?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I was talking to a friend of mine and at one point I said

> So, you're a revolutionist.

He corrected me (in a very polite way) by saying that "revolutionist" is a word that does not exist, the correct would be revolutionary. I perfectly understand his point and agree that the word revolutionary is definitively better in this sentence.

But one thing intrigued me a lot... I have followed Starcraft for many years (I like the game a lot) and my favorite player of all time is [Bisu](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft/Bisu), one of Bisu's nicknames is "The Revolutionist" and that was the main reason I chose the word "revolutionist" instead of revolutionary.

Searching online I found some dictionaries that define the word "revolutionist". The problem is that renowned dictionaries such as Oxford and Cambridge do not present such word in their dictionaries (at least not on the free online version).

And that brings us to my fateful question: **Is "revolutionist" a real word?**

Comment: Have you tried [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionist) ? Which gives the one word definition "revolutionary" .

Comment: I accesed this website, but I didn't know if it was "reliable".

Comment: Merriam-Webster is the American equivalent of the OED. It's the go to dictionary in the USA and is often quoted here and on ELL.

Comment: Collins and AHD both contain the word.

Comment: What is a "real word"? If you've said it then it exists.

Comment: The free online version of Oxford (now called Lexico) does indeed provide a [definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/revolutionist) of the word.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've just 'said' mnmnmn, but it's still not a word. Candidate words are vetted by usage panels; this means (a) the candidate words exist; (b) their wordness is not axiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - There's a difference between "real" and "standard". Candidates for inclusion in a dictionary are vetted, but at that point such words are already in use which is why they're on the candidate list in the first place. If you invent a new word derived from standard words such that most English speakers immediately understand what you mean by it I think it's reasonable to call that a "real" word - you've used it and been understood! - it's just nonstandard.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're confusing the issue. The moot point is what actually  can be claimed to be a word, not a 'real word' or a 'standard word'. And as has been discussed here before, this is a serious problem. In spite of the accepted answer given in the related thread, the answer is dependent on the definition adopted for 'word', and without an 'Académie', 'word' remains ill-defined. '... most English speakers immediately understand' ... but **who decides** whether this is the case for candidate word 23142? Is a 'revolutionist' simply a traditional revolutionary, or is this a believer in a new ism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/164977?redirectedFrom=revolutionist#eid) would seem to concur, and that it would be synonymous with *Revolutionary*

> 2. An advocate of or participant in revolution; a revolutionary.

It would also be allowed on [CountDown](http://wiki.apterous.org/Oxford_Dictionary_of_English)